# Exported Image Does Not Match Current Display On Web Page

Tags: highcharts

We are using HighStock 1.3.1 and the Java+PhantomJS export server (using same version of this exporter as the HighStock). We create some charts on the page. We allow the user to show/hide series or change the type of the series (bar/line/scatter). We have a menu that lets the user select what kind of export to make:

```
    <select size="4"
       name="ctl00$Main_content$ctlMainResultsGraph$lstExportOptions"
       id="ctl00_Main_content_ctlMainResultsGraph_lstExportOptions"
       class="chartMainmenu_body"
       onchange="
        var chart = $('#chartMain').highcharts();
        switch (this.value) {
         case 'JPEG': chart.exportChart({type: 'image/jpeg'}); break;
         case 'PNG': chart.exportChart({type: 'image/png'}); break;
         case 'SVG': chart.exportChart({type: 'image/svg+xml'}); break;
         case 'PDF': chart.exportChart({type: 'application/pdf'}); break;
        }"
      style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">
        <option value="JPEG">JPEG</option>
        <option value="PNG">PNG</option>
        <option value="SVG">SVG</option>
        <option value="PDF">PDF</option>
    </select>
```

When we execute this we do get an exported chart - however it is the original chart that was created on page load. The interesting thing is that if we click on the legend such that only one series is visible on the chart and then change its type from bar to scatter and then export the chart we show all series on the chart but all are a scatter type. So it looks like some of the chart changes are being "kept" and sent out via the export method but not all.

Lists of test paths used:

1. Initial load - export (any option) and chart looks like what is on
   page.
2. Uncheck one item in the legend such that only 3 are visible on
   chart. Export the chart and it looks just like the image in path 1.
3. Go to single series and change chart type to scatter such that just
   one series is shown in the chart. Export the chart and the image
   looks like what is in path 1 only all series are scatter type.

I am **not** able to reproduce this on jsFiddle but this is what our code looks like stripped down to just the important parts: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/sGmE4/).

Comment: Is this the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990357/highcharts-export-breaks-after-resetting-chart-options) issue?

Comment: @PawełFus, It is a bit different. This issue was regardless of resetting the chart or not.

Comment: I think the answer is the same - to use `jQuery.extend()` function to make sure that only copy is passed to Highcharts constructor.