# HighCharts Export Breaks After Resetting Chart Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

On initial load of a page we set the chart options and create the chart. We allow the user to manipulate which series items are shown/hidden and also to change what the type of each series is. We also have a "Reset Chart" action that will revert the chart back to its original load setup. Once the user resets the chart any changes made to chart are not reflected on the exported image except if the user has changed their series chart type. An example jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/FfzaH/) that demonstrates this issue.

After the chart loads click on a export type and you see that they match. Now deselect one of the series from the legend and export again - note that the export and page still match. Now select "single series" from the drop down and export - again they match. Now click on Reset Chart or select "multi series" from the drop down. This brings the chart to the way it looked when it was initially loaded. Now deselect a series and export - they no longer match. The exported image still has all series selected. Now select "single series" again and change the type to "line" and export - again, all series are shown but they are all line type.

This is how I am resetting the chart on the "Reset Chart" click action:

```
   //reset Main Chart chart to original specs
    resetMainChart.live('click', function () {
        forceResetChart(chartMainLoc);
    });
...
function forceResetChart(chart) {
    if (mainGraphMode.is(':visible')) {
        if (mainGraphMode.val() == 'multiple') {
            //if (mainGraphFormatType.val() != 'null') {
            //    mainGraphFormatType.val('null');
            //}
            mainGraphFormatType.val('null');
        } else {
            mainGraphMode.val('multiple');
            mainGraphFormatType.val('null');
        }
        mainGraphFormatType.hide();
        mainGraphFormatDefault.show();
    } else {
        mainGraphFormatType.val('null');
    }
    $('#chartMain').highcharts().destroy();
    chartMainLoc = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChartMain, highlightSer);
}
```

I am at a loss here as to why resetting the chart in this fashion breaks the exporting. I have read some responses to other questions stating that we should get the SVG of the currently displayed chart and send it to the export method. I am not sure how to do that. The docs state that the getSVG() method gets the SVG string of the *intially* loaded chart - not the active chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is nothing wrong, it works exactly as you written. Consider this:

```
chartMainLoc = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChartMain, highlightSer);
```

In `highlightSer` you are displaying all series. When exporting chart, chart is created from the beginning, and callback is used once again, so all series are visible. Remove `highlightSer` callback and you will see the difference.

Comment: Okay, but then I am changing what is on the chart - which series shown etc. Why is it that on initial load I can manipulate the chart as I see fit but if I reset the chart to initial load settings and manipulate the chart the export options do not "see" the updated chart? If I remove the `highlightSer` callback then only the series I had selected from the single series view is shown as well - even though the `optionsChartMain` says all series `visible: true`. I am stuck between 2 errors/failures.

Comment: Use `jQuery.extend(true, {}, options);` to use only copy for a chart, instead of options itself. See: http://jsfiddle.net/FfzaH/4/

Comment: Okay, this seems to do the trick. What exactly is this doing, though?

Comment: Making a deep copy of an object, so Highcharts doesn't have access to options. So properties like visibility etc. aren't changed.

Comment: I see. So the optionsChartMain that I set previously on chart creation on page load was modified somehow? Still not sure how that could have occurred.

Comment: I'm not sure what should I answer - that's how you can access via `this` object, when using `prototype.call()` in JS? Or simple:  http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/505/

Comment: Okay...that is sort of what is happening the other way. I initially create the chart on load from `optionsChartMain` which I thought would be static. I then modify the chart via the gui (switch on/off series and types). I then want to reset the chart back to initial state via `optionsChartMain` which I have not redefined. If I did not call back `highlightSer` it still kept the chart selected series visible only. Even though I have again modified the chart it does not "see" any changes made other than chart type after this `highlightSer` callback - this is the part I do not understand.

Comment: If you will add points, or modify colors, or some other changes using `series.update()`you will get the same effect (as long as you are using object, instead of copy). Callback is called after chart for exporting is recreated - so it overwrites series visibility. For example if you will add AJAX call in that callback, on exported chart you will get two series.

Comment: Now I get it. The callback is not just called upon creation of the chart - it is also called when the export method is used. So when the user exports it also "makes" the chart with `Highcharts.Chart(optionsChartMain, highlightSer)`. That makes sense now. I thought that when I did `chartMainLoc = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChartMain, highlightSer);` that was the end of the `highlightSer`. Many thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes, indeed. `chart.exportChart()` uses `getSVG()` which creates duplicate of a chart from initial options and merge with changes done in real time. And after that, calls callback once again. It's useful when you want to add custom drawnings on a chart, and you want them exported.